# Can a stream cipher with a big S-box create ASIC-resistance?

Tags: hash, s-boxes, rc4, proof-of-work

For a proof of work system a hash algorithm generates one pseudorandom index each round, in the same manner as RC4 and Spritz do. And it uses a bigger S-box, e.g. 2^20 numbers. The actual hash would be the first 32 output bytes of the stream cipher after dropping a certain number of rounds.

Would this be sufficient to get ASIC-resistance in a cryptocurrency?

Comment: Perhaps some more explanation would help.  Yesteryear's ASIC is last year's FPGA which you can do today on a CPU /GPU.   It's only incremental speed /footprint improvement. Wouldn't a simple larger s-box /memory be negated tomorrow by Moore's Law..? Do you know that there's a bitcoin.SE forum?  They deal with alternative currencies as well.  And they know ASIC manufacture /development.

Comment: Generally, people do not deal with the "exotic" ASICs, and this is where I do design.  Basically, you are physically bound by a 2x2cm reticle.  I can also get 4GiB on die via through vias so most things that are "memory hard" are not hard with custom hardware because all of my memory on-die.   We were cranking things out on 14nm 5 years before it was a commodity process because we aren't selling widgets.  For this reason, there's really not "ASIC" resistance in a general sense if you aren't in the constrained world.

Comment: @bdegnan Sounds like a bit of an answer to me :-)

Comment: @PaulUszak well, I would need specifics of implementation for a proper hardware for an answer.   Most people just think in the Intel/FPGA box.  The real innovation is outside of that.  Most everything that people consider to be "hard" I've seen an "easy" version of at the GOMAC conference.   It's always just a matter of reference frame and available tools.